# Delete ROW where Value in column is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete-row

How do I delete out any rows from a table named:

```
bhxsql2014-dev.dbo.EUACTIVESTORES
```

Where the column [Store No] has a NULL value

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Use `IS` operator `Delete from [bhxsql2014-dev].dbo.EUACTIVESTORES Where [Store No] IS NULL`

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE [Store No] IS NULL`.

Comment: The title of the question had already the solution. ;)

Comment: I see that now, still learning here...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
delete from [bhxsql2014-dev].dbo.EUACTIVESTORES
where [Store No] is null
```